# Нужна помощь в Beautiful Soup

Tags: python

Хочу написать простой парсер, чтобы проверял, вышла серия или нет.
Если серия не вышла, то на сайте выложен просто трейлер:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на сайт:
Как мне через BS вытащить вот эту часть сайта?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так:

```
 html = BS(response.content,'html.parser')
    serialName = html.select('title')[0].text
    tag = False
    for el in html.select('a'):
        print(el.text)
```

Но не вышло

Comment: Приведите кусок `html` текста - текстом и приложите ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Ссылка на сайт - http://coldfilm.ws/news/flehsh_6_sezon_9_serija_smotret_onlajn/2019-12-11-19134
html содержимое можно просмотреть через F12, если не ошибаюсь. В комментарие не очень удобно скидывать код

Comment: @ЛёняДекарт в комментарии неудобно, а в вопросе удобно. Кнопка "править".

Comment: Попробуйте `html.find('a', {'class': 'ytp-title-link yt-uix-sessionlink'})`

Comment: *>>вот эту часть сайта* - эта часть - это часть не coldfilm.ws. Это уже `<iframe>`, который подгружается с youtube. *>>вытащить* - сделать запрос по тому же адресу, что это делает сам сайт - `<iframe allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AHPYw8ukbYM" width="610"></iframe>`.

Comment: Что конкретно надо "вытащить"? Строку `The Flash 6x09 Trailer #2 Season 6 Episode 9 Extended Promo/Preview HD "Crisis on Infinite Earths"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**А вот готовый парсер**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req
url = "http://coldfilm.ws/news/flehsh_6_sezon_9_serija_smotret_onlajn/2019-12-11-19134"
s = req.session()
response = s.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
find = html.find('div', {'class': 'kino-desc full-text clearfix'}).find('img').get("title")
print(find)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]